# Accessing private variables in Java via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to write a method that will get a private field in a class using reflection.

Here's my class (simplified for this example):

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int myField;

    public SomeClass() {
        myField = 42;
    }

    public static Object getInstanceField(Object instance, String fieldName) throws Throwable {
        Field field = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        return field.get(instance);
    }
}
```

So say I do this:

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
Object val = SomeClass.getInstanceField(c, "myField");
```

I'm getting an `IllegalAccessException` because `myField` is private. Is there a way to get/set private variables using reflection?  (I've done it in C#, but this is the first time I've tried it in Java).  If you're wondering why there is the need to do such madness :), it's because sometimes during unit testing it's handy to set private variables to bogus values for failure testing, etc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Figured it out. Need

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: bear in mind that this won't work if there is PermissionManager

Comment: This can improve the performance marginally even if the member is otherwise accessible (as it turns the checks off)

Comment: +1 this just saved me some frustration :)