# Access a private variable of the super() class in Java - JChart2D

Tags: java, inheritance

I have extended a class in Java that has a private variable that I want to get the value of before it is changed. There are no methods to access this variable in the super class. I have tried `super().m_zoomArea` (the variable is in the `ZoomableChart` class of jChart2D). The variable is updated when the `mouseDragged` method is called. I have overridden this method and would like to get the value of the variable before it is updated.

Answer (score 27):

You can access private variable of any class, but it's a bad idea, because you're breaking one of the basic principles of OOP - encapsulation.

But sometimes programmer are forced to break it. Here is the code, which solves your problem:

Extended class

```
public class ExtZoomableChart
extends ZoomableChart {

public Rectangle2D getZoomArea() {
    try {
        Field field = ZoomableChart.class.getDeclaredField("m_zoomArea");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(this);
        field.setAccessible(false);

        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (Rectangle2D.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
            return (Rectangle2D) value;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong value");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

and call example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtZoomableChart extZoomableChart = new ExtZoomableChart();

        Rectangle2D d = extZoomableChart.getZoomArea();
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

You don't need to extend ZoomableChart to get private variable. You can get it value almost from everywhere. But remember - usually it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 15):

You can't. The whole point of it being *private* is that you can't get at the variable. If the class hasn't given any way of finding it out, you can't get it. That may or may not be a design flaw in the class, but unless you use reflection with suitable privileges (which I *don't* recommend - you're basically relying on private implementation details) you're going to have to think of an alternative approach.

Answer (score 4):

You could use reflection but it's a bad idea. A private field is private because the developer doesn't want you to mess with it.

I won't give you the way to do it here, but if you **really** know what you do, follow the links below at your own risks. Again, you shouldn't even think about doing this.

---

**On the same topic :**

- [Does reflection breaks the idea of private methods, because private methods can be access outside of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300680/does-reflection-breaks-the-idea-of-private-methods-because-private-methods-can-b)
- [Accessing private variables in Java via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771744/accessing-private-variables-in-java-via-reflection)
- [Is it possible in Java to access private fields via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555658/is-it-possible-in-java-to-access-private-fields-via-reflection)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access private variables from outside of the class. In order to access it you would have to have it be protected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Reflection API (Specifically, see the setAccessible() method). Anyway, this is a hack and may not work if there is a SecurityManager installed in the VM.