# make variable name from other variable value

Tags: java, android

Basically I'm trying to automate process of

```
mDrawable[0] = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img0);
mDrawable[1] = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1);
mDrawable[2] = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2);
mDrawable[3] = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3);
mDrawable[4] = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4);
```

etc..

to a loop:

```
for(int i = 0;i<=15;i++)
{       
mDrawable[i] = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.**img+i**);       
}
```

So how do I make up this resource name **img4** from **i** loop variable

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you want to implement [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/?p=1718) kind of example.

This is helpful when you want to implement findViewById() inside a loop when there are many number of views with just a difference like "counter" varialbe 1, 2,3,4,5,etc.

```
for(int i=0; i<15; i++) 
{
    String imageID = "img" + (i);
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageID, "drawable", getPackageName());

  /* if you want to reference any widgets like Button, TextView, ImageView, etc. then write below code:

    //int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageID, "id", getPackageName());   
  */
}
```

Comment: `"id"` is not valid here since those are drawable ids, use `"drawable"` instead. Otherwise you'll end with 0, which is a invalid reference.

Comment: `getPackageName()` is a `Context` method, so if you are not in a class that extends context (e.g. a activity or a service) you have to get hold of a context instance and use `ctx.getPackageName()`. Alternatively use a String literal `"com.your.packagename"` instead.

Comment: @alextsc thats the exact catch dear. thanx

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`Resources.getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Small snippet from the top of my head:

```
for(int i = 0;i<=15;i++)
{   
    int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
    mDrawable[i] = this.getResources().getDrawable(id);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection. However, given the overhead of doing the reflection I would suggest with sticking with the above code unless you have a lot more than 4 elements.

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771744/accessing-private-variables-in-java-via-reflection)

[Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Comment: According to his loop, he has 16 of them

Comment: Good catch. I would still code it out rather than using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid [Resource.getIndentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (the use of which is discouraged), you could generate an array of ids and iterate through them

```
int ids[] = { R.drawable.img0, R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.differentnames, R.drawable.whatever /*etc*/ };
mDrawables = new Drawable[ids.length];
for(int i = 0, s = ids.length; i < s; i++)
{       
    mDrawables[i] = this.getResources().getDrawable(ids[i]);       
}
```