# Android: How to get image from resource file

Tags: android

Usually, I get the image and binding them to the `ImageView` something like:

```
Integer[] icon = {R.drawable.avatar1, R.drawable.avatar2}; 
imageView_1.setImageResource(icon [0]);
imageView_2.setImageResource(icon [1]);
```

Anybody know is there is any other way to declare the image name on the resource file `strings.xml`? And how do we add them to `ImageView`?

Comment: Very vague question. Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: means that you want to refer avatar images based on the counter varialble like 1, 2,3,4 and so on, is it the case you want to implement?

Comment: If this is the case then here is more info for the same problem: [make variable name from other variable value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135791/make-variable-name-from-other-variable-value/8135837#8135837)

Comment: This line int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageID, "drawable", getPackageName());
 helped me alot, tks Paresh Mayani ....

Answer (score 3):

To **get the resource ID** from a resource, such as a translation string or a resource drawable,  in general, you can use (as AdrDev_CTS pointed out):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageID, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

You can then use this resId in a view you have.

Answer (score 0):

Note that getIdentifier(imageID, "drawable", getPackageName()) is considered really slow and it's not adviced to use it..

> use of [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  function is discouraged. It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.