# how to mock a class's inner static class's private field

Tags: testing, mockito

i'm test a MR class which has mapper/reducer as inner static classes. the mapper has a private field which consume too much memory to make the test failed, i want to use a mock object for that field, but not sure how to do that, here is my code:

```
public class Aggregator extends Configured implements Tool {
   public static class AggregatorMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, GeneralKey, Text) {
      private LookupService lookupService = null;   <--- the object i want to mock
   }
}
```

i tried to mockito but seems no way to mock it. any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: If this variable is referencing an object that takes up too much memory, then you must be assigning it later in your code.  So replacing it with a mock at the beginning of your test isn't going to help you at all.  Can you post the part of your code where this variable is actually being assigned, so that we can see how best to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to access and modify any property of any object you want.  There are several questions on SO that answer this quite well already, for example:

- [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection).
- [Accessing private variables in Java via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771744/accessing-private-variables-in-java-via-reflection)
- [Instantiate private inner class with java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112166/instantiate-private-inner-class-with-java-reflection)